# Getting rid of spaces in filenames (Unix/Linux)

Tags: bash, filenames, solaris, spaces

The problem is well-known yet I cannot find a solution: I wish to rename directories and files, replacing the spaces by underscores. The below code does not work, for some unclear reason. This is in bash on Solaris 11.

```
find $BASEDIR -type d |grep ' ' | awk '{print "\"" $0 "\""}' >$TMPFIL
cat $TMPFIL | while read FILNAM ; do
 F2=$(echo $FILNAM | sed -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/\"//g')
 CMD="mv "$FILNAM" "$F2
 echo "Will execute: "$CMD
 $CMD
 done
```

Output looks like

```
Will execute: 
mv "/opt/pakket/smbdata/INTSCAN/ipmdata/Errors/Herstart 2015-01-07" /opt/pakket/smbdata/INTSCAN/ipmdata/Errors/Herstart_2015-01-07
mv: /opt/pakket/smbdata/INTSCAN/ipmdata/Errors/Herstart_2015-01-07 not found
```

it complains about not finding the second argument. When I copy and paste the command it generates, and launch it "manually", everything works fine, though.

Comment: Do you have `rename` utility available?

Comment: Negative:   # type rename    
    -bash: type: rename: not found

Comment: Is a Python answer welcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
find /path/to/dir -depth -name '*[[:space:]]*' -execdir bash -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0//[[:space:]]/_}"' {} \;
```

This will not rename anything, only show the commands that will be executed. Remove the `echo` in front of `mv` to actually perform the renaming.

If your `find` doesn't support `-execdir` (which seems to be the case on your Solaris), this should do:

```
find -depth -name '*[[:space:]]*' -exec bash -c 'd=${0%/*} b=${0##*/}; echo mv "$d/$b" "$d/${b//[[:space:]]/_}"' {} \;
```

Comment: Too bad: the 'find' in Solaris does not know the -execdir option. /usr/xpg4/bin/find . -depth -name '*[[:space:]]*' -execdir bash -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0//[[:space:]]/_}"' {} \;
/usr/xpg4/bin/find: bad option -execdir

Comment: @KarelAdams Oh, sorry, I overlooked the [tag:solaris] tag!

Comment: This worked like a charm, many thanks. One single directory still had an issue, I think this was because there several blanks in its name. But that was easily fixed manually.